How do I create a list of the indices for a list of 3D vertices?
I have this set of 3 D vertices. Each line holds the coordinates of two (2) different points, so each line is like x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2.
0.142000E+03 -.600000E+03 0.262790E+04 -.142000E+03 -.600000E+03 0.262790E+04
-.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04
0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.238750E+04
0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 -.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04
-.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.238750E+04 0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.238750E+04
-.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.262800E+04 0.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.262800E+04
0.984000E+02 0.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 -.984000E+02 0.599999E+03 0.258430E+04
0.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.262800E+04 0.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.234400E+04

I wanted to first separate each triplet of vertices, then combine all triplets into a list A. Then, from this list, I wanted to create a list B of unique triplets and give each of them an index. From there, I wanted to create a list C of the indexes of each element in A according to the unique triplet list B. I essentially wanted to make a .off file with groups of indices making a face.
I tried this code in Python:
import re

def takeNumFaces(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        second_line = lines[1].strip()
        numbers = second_line.split()
        faces = int(numbers[1])
    return(faces)

def takeNumPoints(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        second_line = lines[1].strip()
        numbers = second_line.split()
        points = int(numbers[2])
    return(points)

geofile = "C:/mygeofile.geo"

geofaces = takeNumFaces(geofile)
facepoints = takeNumPoints(geofile)
#print(geofaces, facepoints)

def gatherVertices(filepath):
    vertices = []
    unique_vert = []
    index = 0
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines[2 : 2*geofaces + 2]:
            parts = re.findall(r'[-0]\.\d+E[+-]\d{2}', line)
            # print(parts)
            for i in range(0, len(parts), 3):
                vertex = [parts[i], parts[i+1], parts[i+2]]
                #print(vertex)
                vertices.append(vertex)
        
    return vertices
                
vertices = gatherVertices(geofile)
#print(vertices)
unique_vertices = set(tuple(vertex) for vertex in vertices)
unique_vertices_list = [list(vertex) for vertex in unique_vertices]
# print(len(unique_vertices), len(vertices))
# for vertex in unique_vertices_list:
#     print(vertex)

def getVertexIndices(vertices1, vertices2):
    # Convert vertices2 to tuples (since unique_vertices_list is already list of lists)
    unique_vertices_tuples = [tuple(vertex) for vertex in vertices2]
    
    # Create a mapping of vertices to indices
    vertex_to_index = {tuple(vertex): index for index, vertex in enumerate(unique_vertices_tuples)}
    # print(vertex_to_index)
    # Get the index of each vertex in vertices1 in vertices2
    index_list = [vertex_to_index[tuple(vertex)] for vertex in vertices1]

    return index_list

index_list = getVertexIndices(vertices, unique_vertices_list)
# for index in index_list:
#     print(index)
# print(len(index_list))

# num = 2000
# if num in index_list:
#     print(f"{num} is in the list")
# else:
#     print(f"{num} is not in the list")

def groupFaces(indices):
    faces = [indices[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(indices), 4)]
    return faces

face_list = groupFaces(index_list)
# for face in face_list:
#     print(face)

off_file = "C:/myPrivateFilePath"

object_dimension = 3

groupsize = facepoints // object_dimension 

def write_off(offpath):
    with open(offpath, 'w') as file:
        file.write("OFF\n")
        file.write(f"{len(vertices)} {geofaces} 0\n")

        for vertex in vertices:
            file.write(" ".join(vertex) + "\n")

        for face in face_list:
            line = f"{groupsize} " + " ".join(map(str, face)) + "\n"
            file.write(line)


write_off(off_file)



I managed to make a list of triplets like [0.142000E+03, -.600000E+03, 0.262790E+04], [-.142000E+03, -.600000E+03, 0.262790E+04] etc. But for some reason my indices were shuffled and I got an index_list beginning with :
4 547 1181 1335 867
4 1181 2243 182 1335
4 2243 787 2275 182
4 787 547 867 2275


So the first group isn't even made with the first four (4) vertex triplets. I was supposed to grab the index of each element (a vertex triplet) in vertices, then give its index (according to unique_vertices_list) to index_list.
How do I make sure that the vertex triplets' indices appear in order (i.e, element 0 of vertices, is element 0 of the unique list, therefore element 0 of the index_list is 0)?

that data file seems to be missing the first two lines

It seems like the use of set to get unique vertices is the heart of the problem. set is not ordered. There's another SO question linked below that talks about this problem. There's a lot of detail in the answers that you might not need, but you can probably get started by adapting the top bit of code from the top answer:
def get_unique(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

How do I remove duplicates from a list, while preserving order?

OK, I've added some more detail adapted from the link.

It might be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other, particularly if you think the other question has quality detailed answers.

After you arrange your list to group of 2 items use dictionary to give every group an index while keeping the order
vertices = ['0.142000E+03', '-.600000E+03', '0.262790E+04', '-.142000E+03', '-.600000E+03', '0.262790E+04',
            '-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04', '0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04',
            '0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04', '0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04',
            '0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04', '-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04',
            '-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04', '0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04',
            '-.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04', '0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04',
            '0.984000E+02', '0.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04', '-.984000E+02', '0.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04',
            '0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04', '0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.234400E+04']

a = [vertices[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(vertices), 3)]
print('a:', a)

b = dict.fromkeys(tuple(x) for x in a)
for i, x in enumerate(b):
    b[x] = i
print('b:', list(b.keys()))

c = [[b[tuple(x)] for x in a][i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
print('c:', c)

Output
a: [['0.142000E+03', '-.600000E+03', '0.262790E+04'], ['-.142000E+03', '-.600000E+03', '0.262790E+04'], ['-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'], ['0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'], ['0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'], ['0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04'], ['0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'], ['-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'], ['-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04'], ['0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04'], ['-.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04'], ['0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04'], ['0.984000E+02', '0.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'], ['-.984000E+02', '0.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'], ['0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04'], ['0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.234400E+04']]
b: [('0.142000E+03', '-.600000E+03', '0.262790E+04'), ('-.142000E+03', '-.600000E+03', '0.262790E+04'), ('-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'), ('0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'), ('0.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04'), ('-.984000E+02', '-.599999E+03', '0.238750E+04'), ('-.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04'), ('0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.262800E+04'), ('0.984000E+02', '0.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'), ('-.984000E+02', '0.599999E+03', '0.258430E+04'), ('0.142000E+03', '0.600000E+03', '0.234400E+04')]
c: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 3, 4], [3, 2, 5], [4, 6, 7], [8, 9, 7], [10]]


If you have a list of vertices, and you want the index to refer to its index in that list, then you need a data structure that preserves that index. I'd suggest using enumerate(vertices) to build a dict, and then just put them in a dict so they stay together AND dedup.
import re
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pprint

# This recipe is in the itertools documenation, or can be pip installed.
from more_itertools import grouper

# I had to re-write the data reader because it needed header lines you didn't include
def gather_vertices(file):
    vertices = []
    for line in file:
        parts = re.findall(r'[-0]\.\d+E[+-]\d{2}', line)
        assert len(parts) % 3 == 0
        vertices.extend(list(grouper(parts,3)))
    return vertices

RAW_DATA = """0.142000E+03 -.600000E+03 0.262790E+04 -.142000E+03 -.600000E+03 0.262790E+04
-.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04
0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.238750E+04
0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 -.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.258430E+04
-.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.238750E+04 0.984000E+02 -.599999E+03 0.238750E+04
-.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.262800E+04 0.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.262800E+04
0.984000E+02 0.599999E+03 0.258430E+04 -.984000E+02 0.599999E+03 0.258430E+04
0.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.262800E+04 0.142000E+03 0.600000E+03 0.234400E+04
"""

with StringIO(RAW_DATA) as handle:
    vertices = gather_vertices(handle)

# build dict which removes duplicates and associates the vertex with its index.
unique_vertices = {}
for index, vertex in enumerate(vertices):
    if vertex not in unique_vertices:
        unique_vertices[vertex] = index
print('dict of each vertex with its first index')
pprint(unique_vertices)
print()

# now we build the faces, and prove we can get the original value
faces = list(grouper(vertices, 4))
for count, face in enumerate(faces):
    indexed_face = [unique_vertices[v] for v in face]
    recovered_face = [vertices[index] for index in indexed_face]
    print(f'face {count} is {indexed_face}, which is {recovered_face}')

